# Getting SQLCODE and SQLSTATE from inner SQL call in procedure DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, db2

I have this procedure:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_TEST
                                 ( IN QUERY VARCHAR(24576),
                                   IN LOGTBL_VAR VARCHAR(20) ) 
                                   LANGUAGE SQL 
                                   SPECIFIC LOG_TEST
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_QUERY VARCHAR(24576);
DECLARE V_ERRORMSG VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE V_SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_INS_STRING VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE STMT STATEMENT;
DECLARE STMT_INS STATEMENT;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS
EXCEPTION
1 V_ERRORMSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
VALUES(SQLSTATE,SQLCODE)INTO V_SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE;
END;

SET V_QUERY = QUERY;
PREPARE STMT FROM V_QUERY;
EXECUTE STMT;

SET V_QUERY     = REPLACE(V_QUERY,'''', ''''''); 
SET V_INS_STRING= 'INSERT INTO '||LOGTBL_VAR||'(QUERY, SQL_CODE, SQL_STATE, ERROR_MSG, BEZUG, TIME) VALUES ('''||V_QUERY||''', '||V_SQLCODE||', '''||V_SQLSTATE||''', '''||V_ERRORMSG||''')';
 PREPARE STMT_INS FROM V_INS_STRING;
 EXECUTE STMT_INS;

 END@
```

The procedure works well and all is good but one thing. If the query that is given via parameter is invalid I always get SQLCODE -727 and SQLSTATE 56098 which is a general error for the procedure itself, however I need the SQLCODE and SQLSTATE that the query is causing so I can see what is wrong with the query itself. How can I get that?

I am running DB2 on Windows v10.5

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT statement is not correct - different number of columns (6) and values (4).
What do you get exactly in the LOG_TEST table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_TEST (
  IN QUERY VARCHAR(24576)
, IN LOGTBL_VAR VARCHAR(20)
) 
SPECIFIC LOG_TEST
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_ERRORMSG VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE V_SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 V_ERRORMSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  VALUES(SQLSTATE,SQLCODE) INTO V_SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE;
END;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY;

PREPARE STMT_INS FROM 'INSERT INTO '||LOGTBL_VAR||'(QUERY, SQL_CODE, SQL_STATE, ERROR_MSG) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
EXECUTE STMT_INS USING QUERY, V_SQLCODE, V_SQLSTATE, V_ERRORMSG;

END@

CREATE TABLE LOG_TEST(QUERY VARCHAR(1000), SQL_CODE INT, SQL_STATE CHAR(5), ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(1000)) IN USERSPACE1@

CALL LOG_TEST('DELETE FROM LOG_TEST - WRONG QUERY', 'LOG_TEST')@
SELECT * FROM LOG_TEST@
```

If you want to run SELECT statements and get results, then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_TEST (
  IN QUERY VARCHAR(24576)
, IN LOGTBL_VAR VARCHAR(20)
, OUT RES INT
) 
SPECIFIC LOG_TEST
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_ERRORMSG VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE V_SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE V_SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE V_QUERY VARCHAR(24576);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 V_ERRORMSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  VALUES(SQLSTATE,SQLCODE) INTO V_SQLSTATE, V_SQLCODE;
END;

SET V_QUERY='SET (?) = ('||REPLACE(QUERY, '''', '''''')||')';
PREPARE STMT_SEL FROM V_QUERY;
EXECUTE STMT_SEL INTO RES;

PREPARE STMT_INS FROM 'INSERT INTO '||LOGTBL_VAR||'(QUERY, SQL_CODE, SQL_STATE, ERROR_MSG) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
EXECUTE STMT_INS USING QUERY, V_SQLCODE, V_SQLSTATE, V_ERRORMSG;

END@
```

Comment: I simplified the source there are 6 values. Now it works for all but a select query. 
Can you use execute immediate for a select query like execute immediate query into variable? (Query being a select count(*) )

Comment: I tried 'SET(?)=('||QUERY||')' INTO VARIABLE; but that doesn't compile

Comment: You can't run execute immediate for SELECT statements. I've updated the example.

Comment: what if I only want the code and state not the result of the select? I only need code and state, the result is only because I haven't found a normal select query way. But maybe I should open a new question for that

Comment: It's quite unusual to run SELECT statements and don't consume their results. Running select statements just to log their calls? Really strange...

Comment: Yeah but I only need the code and state of it. The result is not of interest. Just checking if the statement is correct and would deliever a result

Comment: Like a kind of debugger. I throw queries at it and see if they are correct or not

Comment: `DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR STMT_SEL; ... PREPARE STMT_SEL FROM V_QUERY; OPEN C1; CLOSE C1;` or even just stop on PREPARE for all types of queries, if you don't want to really run them...

Comment: I get -504 something with fetch or close but not -204. The query has a wrong table name so the error code should be 204. Any idea why?

Comment: I opened this as a new question, might help others to. Of course I mentioned your great help there too.